Is there a workaround to create the appearance of stretched points based on different values for each point?
I'm plotting a meal pattern analysis for mice. The lines on the Y axis represent each mouse, the X axis is time, and the point size is meal size. I also have data for meal duration and I'd like to find a way to elongate each point based on the duration. The points don't need to taper like my example but this was the easiest way to create it in Illustrator.
The meal durations are measured discretely in 15 minute increments and are never longer than an hour so I was thinking maybe there is a way to create a custom shape that varies in length for 15, 30, 45, and 60 minutes points?
I read ggplot documentation but couldn't find anything that exactly fits what I am looking for.

Reproducible example:
library(ggplot2)

mealsizes = rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd =1)
mealsizes[mealsizes < 0] = 0

mealtimes = runif(100, min = 0, max = 24)

subjects = rep(seq(1,10,1), times = 10)

group = rep(c(1,2), times = 50)

df = data.frame(time = mealtimes, size = mealsizes, subject = subjects, 
                group = group)

ggplot(data = df, aes(time, subject, color = group, size = size)) + 
  geom_point(pch=21) +
  theme_minimal()


I think the shape does not really fit. It does not make sense to me that the 15 minute intervals get thinner with time. What about lines?

To me the more natural way to do this would be to use a different geom, such as geom_segment(). You could have a column for beginning and ending time to each meal that would be mapped to the x and xend aesthetics of the segment. Would you be open to that approach?

There’s geom_ellipse() in ‘ggforce’, but it doesn’t allow drawing the neat raindrop shapes your screenshot shows. For that you’d need to develop your own geometry. This is possible but effectively undocumented (well…) and fairly complex. (And the geom_ellipse() aesthetics mapping doesn’t directly fit your data, you’d have to transform it first using the equation for an ellipsis.)

I suggest using ggforce::geom_bspline_closed0 with some wrangling to define control points for each observation. By trial and error, it looks like we can get pretty good alignment between the shape and the actual duration by making the control points overshoot the intended range.

set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(time = runif(50, min = 0, max = 24),
               duration = rpois(50, 20)/10,
               size = pmax(0, rnorm(50, mean = 2, sd = 1)),
               subjects = rep(seq(1,10,1), times = 5),
               group = rep(c(1,2), times = 25))

Here, I take each row and use it to define four control points for a closed spline, where size defines the vertical points, and duration defines the rightmost point. The geom_point() and geom_segment() layers here are to confirm the blobs have approximately the right lengths.
Another approach for better alignment could be to add more control points. For instance, if you double-up the side points, you'll get an "eye" shape that gets very close to the intended points without needing to overshoot. But I don't know a general way to ensure that the shape outline aligns perfectly.
df |>
  mutate(row = row_number()) |>
  reframe(x = time + c(-duration*0.1, pmin(0.5, duration/2), duration * 1.4, 
                       pmin(0.5, duration/2)), 
          y = subjects + c(0, size/10, 0, -size/10),
          .by = c(row, subjects, group)) |>
  ggplot(aes(x, y, color = group, group = row)) +
  ggforce::geom_bspline_closed0(fill = NA) 
  # geom_point(size = 0.2) + 
  # geom_segment(aes(x = time, y = subjects, 
  #                 xend = time + duration, yend = subjects),
  #           size = 0.5, color = "red", data = df, inherit.aes = FALSE)


"Debugging view," showing the control points and the intended durations as segments:


You could use segments:
df$mealduration <- sample(c(.25, .5, .75, 1), size = nrow(df), replace = TRUE)
df$endtime <- df$time + df$mealduration
df$group <- factor(df$group)
df$subject <- factor(df$subject)

ggplot(df, aes(time, xend = endtime, subject, yend = subject, color = group, linewidth = size)) + 
  geom_segment() +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev)


It is worth considering mapping the linewidth to the amount of food consumed in each 15 minute interval though, so that the area of the segment is reflects the amount of food consumed.
